# Is it okay to utilize UserControls if it requires codebehind?

Tags: silverlight, design-patterns, windows-phone-7

I am building a rather large WP7 application and having a lot of fun with it. It is Pivot based and has quite a lot of pivot pages. I dynamically add and remove pivot pages based on what "mode" of the application the user has selected to keep the application look and feel as simple as possible. All is going quite well so far my app is fast responsive, not a memory or resource hog and performs background loading on demand when needed.

The Model layer contains all my business logic that represents what the application is all about. It is clean and separate from the the view-model and view layers.

The View-Model layer is an abstraction of the model to the extent that it needs to interact with the view and also contains the session-ness and workflow aspects of the application in general. It contains objects which represent the Model in a way the View needs to interact with. The view model persists the state of the application in isolated storage and supports tomb-stoning.

The View layer contains a lot of elements pivots, user controls, styles, resources etc in both xaml and the corresponding code behind. I do like Blend and the Xaml designer within visual studio 2010 however I find myself still coding/configuring the view objects within the code behind due to the nature in which they interact with each other. The code behind of the view objects is becoming quite large but still only reflects the state of the view and not the state of the application. I have made use of user controls quite a lot as this lets me build reusable components across many pivot pages however the user controls are not Blend friendly. What I am worried about is that my view might becoming more complex than it needs to be and losing the ability to coordinate the user interface design with tools like expression blend.

By customising the view this way and making use of reusable controls I have reduced my Xaml considerably and don't suffer from bloated Xaml files that other developers have mentioned but lost ability to co-ordinate with Blend. Is there are happy medium to be found? Should I be looking at designing custom controls?

[Edit]

Thanks for your reply. I think it boils down to either a lot of Xaml with a designer or break it down into user controls with more code behind. Since I moved into user controls my mindset has moved back to doing things by hand rather than with a designer (better the devil you know right!). My thoughts are should I make my user controls into skin-able custom controls or just keep going how I am and avoid using the designer. Its a bit of potato-potardo but I don't want to get into bad habits.

Answer (score 0):

Custom Controls (or Templated Controls) are not directly related to your question as far as I can see.  Custom controls are just controls that add new properties, events and methods to an existing control and are still capable of being 'templated' by a designer.

Creating UI in code does make it harder to design the application using Blend (and even the VS designer) because the only way to see the interface is by running the application.

A lot of the logic that creates the UI could possibly be replaced by using the Visual State Manager. Use states of the controls to design them for specific modes of the view. Only when you need extra/new states you will have to create a Custom Control.

As your question is a bit wide, feel free to add comments or extend your question so I can add more details or remove this answer when it is utter nonsense :)